# How to track json request/response changes between two teams and be notified when smth. was changed

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, xsd

**The situation is the following:**

Two teams in different locations are working on the same product, however we don't have access to each other sources. One team - backend (app server), other one - GUI (client side).

Server requests/responses are changing quite frequently, and the second team (client side) knew that too late in the process, by doing sanity,

**Our goal is:** discover issues early in the process or any changes on both sides even before it raises a bug.

**My idea:** All the json response/request supported by App server and used by the UI will be transformed to an xsd (basing this on the fact that json is quite equivalent to xml) and then we will have an xsd that:
1.  server side will maintain and make accessible every build
2.  client side will validate itself against (even on a nightly basis of tests)

**Second idea:** Apps erver will have an integration tests (we have them in any way) that will validate requests/responses formats with some json content let's say stored on the filesystem, as a next step, the test will check if the json format was changed from the previous test runs. Run these integration test on a nightly  basis and send mail to other team once it detects that contract was breached.

**Any other good ideas to track these ongoing changes ?**

Thanks
Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing a classical problem of managing change to a published interface that is used by systems not under your direct control.

Both of your initial ideas are on the right track: the first is a way for your server team to communicate about changes such that there is an obvious way for your client team to see what has changed. The second is a way to catch the situations where that communication fails, so that errors can be detected before they become production issues.

I think the trick is getting the details of this right so that the right people hear about the changes at the right time. To that end, here are some additional ideas, building on your first:

- Have the integration tests be maintained as a joint effort between the client and server teams. The client team can then write tests that verify the expectations their code has made, which the server team can then run in a non-production environment before releasing any changes. This assumes that there is only one client team: if you're working on a public API used by many third-parties then you may have no alternative but for the server team to simply guess what the client's needs are; that is less than ideal but can still work if your API is quite simple and doesn't have too many use-cases to consider.
- Let the client team know early when a breaking change is coming so that they are prepared to solve for it in a calm and relaxed manner, rather than it being a mad scramble to make something work to fix a production issue. Your generated schema can help you with this if you write a tool that is able to look at two versions of the schema and spot any breaking changes before the code is released for the client team to deal with.
- Agree with the client team on what is considered a breaking change and what their client code is expected to simply be robust about. You could agree, for example, that adding a new property to an existing object is not a breaking change and that the client code must simply ignore it, but that requires discipline on the part of the server developers to never add a new property that will change the interpretation of another existing one. Once you have agreed on what constitutes a breaking change the client developers can build their code around those assumptions and the server developers can notice changes that are considered breaking and flag them up for early communication.
- Implement mechanisms to enable multi-step deprecation cycles for certain types of changes. For example, if you routinely rename properties you could build a feature into your server-side code that allows you to declare that one object property is an alias of another. Make the server code then include all of the possible names for a property in the JSON payload at once, so that the client will work regardless of which name it is expecting. You can then tell the client developers that the alias will be maintained for a given time period, after which they are expected to have changed their code to use the new name and you can remove the alias. A related strategy is to auto-generate a simple client library from your schema and have the client team use it rather than direct API access; your client library can then handle these sorts of conversion issues to avoid bloating the objects sent over the wire.

I have applied all of the above strategies to manage change to a web services API I maintain. Each situation is different, but hopefully these thoughts will give you some ideas on how you could achieve a similar effect in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on JSON schema: http://json-schema.org/ 
I personally have not tried this yet but it seems that this is exactly what you need.